# How to get DOMDocument to be nice to ASCII control characters?

Tags: php, html, xml, utf-8, domdocument

The HTML document which I am parsing contains some ASCII control codes. I noticed that PHP's DOMDocument parser truncates text nodes when it finds ASCII control characters within the node, such as

> `Device Control 0x13`
>
> `End of Medium 0x19`
>
> `File Separator 0x1C`
>
> `Group Separator 0x1D`

Is this a bug or a feature? Is there any way to have DOMDocument act otherwise? I resorted to remove this characters before DOM processing, but I wonder if that's the right solution.

Comment: I see that you accepted my answer, were you able to configure the parser as 1.1? Or did you use the work-around of prepending a 1.1 prologue? Or something different? It would be helpful to other people with the same problem if you could show some example code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably both a bug and a feature.

XML 1.0 is [very restrictive](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#charsets) about the ASCII control characters that it will accept. So it seems like your DOMDocument is trying to protect you from yourself by truncating (although it should return some indication of a problem, so I'd call that a bug).

XML 1.1 is [less restrictive](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml11/#charsets); the only thing that it doesn't allow is NUL. So, one possible solution is to configure your DOMDocument object so that it knows it should be managing 1.1.

---

Edit: it [looks like](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) you can pass the XML version number to the DOMDocument constructor (but I'm not a PHP programmer, so don't know if I'm reading the docs correctly).

---

Edit 2: I just reread your question, and realized that your parsing, not constructing. If you prepend a valid 1.1 prologue to the input, that should be a workaround. Or perhaps by constructing the DOMDocument with the correct version number, it will parse correctly without that prologue.

Comment: Even in XML 1.1, the listed characters are RestrictedChar so have to be encoded as character references rather than included as-is!

Comment: I'm not sure that's correct. I assume that you're looking at the `document` production, which contains `(  Char* RestrictedChar    Char*  )`. However, if you follow the links, you'll see that `Char` and `RestrictedChar` overlap, and there's no mention of requiring `RestrictedChar` to be encoded as an entity (at least that I could find) -- they're just identified as "discouraged."

Comment: That's a `-` in front of `(Char* RestrictedChar Char*)`, which means the document must not have RestrictedChar anywhere in it. Indeed, none of the XML parsers I have here will touch such a document.

Answer (score 1):

To add to what kdgregory said about allowable characters, those control characters are not just invalid in XML, but also in SGML. So legacy HTML or XHTML, you're not ever going to be able to parse any of those characters in an HTML document.

(And I have no idea why you would want to. Binary data doesn't belong in [X][HT]ML.)

Comment: Thanks. Anyway, I don't want to add those characters! I'm parsing a web document that someone else authored. These chars were probably pasted from another application (Microsoft?) directly into the web editor or something of that ilk.